# Apply force to a specific point on a rigid body

Tags: physics, unity

In unity I have a rigid body object and would like to apply force to a specific point. For example say I had a cube, I want to hit just the top right corner so it spins as a result. One idea I had considered is spawn a small sphere and fire it at it, then destroy the sphere. But is there a way to just apply the force?

Comment: It's easier for us if you specify the engine in more than just the tag. And what have you tried?

Comment: The first words are the engine I'm using, and the ball thing was all I had tried, and for the record throwing a ball of considerable mass (like a cannon ball) at a ragdoll is incridbly fun

Comment: Woops! Somehow I missed the "in unity" part. I just started at "I have a rigid body" for some reason! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition.html

```
void ApplyForce(Rigidbody body) {
    Vector3 direction = body.transform.position - transform.position;
    body.AddForceAtPosition(direction.normalized, transform.position);
}
```

Comment: I suppose that does answer it. I hadn't found that function. Now I just have to figure out how to get the vector 3 of the point I want to apply force to. I'm guessing the fps tutorial is my next step then